# Flutter - Textfield add new line

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I try to make a TextField with `keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword` to disable the predictive text but with that I can't go to a new line because it's a submit button. I try to add `textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline` but don't work too.

My TextField:

```
TextField(
     focusNode: myFocusNode,
     autocorrect: false,
     enableSuggestions: false,
     toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(copy: false, cut: false, paste: false),
     keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
     textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
     autofocus: true,
     maxLines: null,
     controller: textEditor,
     decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.grey[100])
))));
```

Comment: You could try setting `maxLines:` property to 2 or whatever you want it to be.

Comment: I try but dont' work =/

Comment: Probably because `TextInputType.visiblePassword` disables multiline as passwords are always single line fields.

Comment: Yes it's what I think, but I need to disable the predictive text and to have a new line. `TextInputType.multiline` don't work too.

Comment: You can set maxlines to null or pass any integer value

TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLines: null,
            ),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add my textfield in a RawKeyboardListener and when user press "Enter" it's detect automatically.

```
RawKeyboardListener(
      focusNode: FocusNode(),
      onKey: (event) {
             if(event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)) {
                 int cursorPos = textEditor.selection.base.offset;
                 textEditor.text = textDebut + '\n' + textFin;
                 textEditor.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: cursorPos + 1));}},
child:TextField(
      focusNode: myFocusNode,
      autocorrect: false,
      enableSuggestions: false,
      toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(copy: false, cut: false, paste: false),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
      autofocus: true,
      maxLines: null,
      controller: textEditor,
      decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.grey[100]),
      onChanged: (String text) {print(text);}))
```

Answer (score 7):

You just add below parameter to disable predicting text.

```
enableSuggestions: false,
autocorrect: false,
```

But to enable multiline, you need to change 'keyboardType' to 'TextInputType.multiline'.

```
TextField(
        autocorrect: false,
        enableSuggestions: false,
        toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(copy: false, cut: false, paste: false),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
        autofocus: true,
        maxLines: null,
        decoration: InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.grey[100]))
```

Comment: I already do that but if I put keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline, the predicting text comes back even if I put "enableSuggestions: false, autocorrect: false"

Answer (score 1):

Change  TextInputAction.newline to  TextInputAction.next

```
TextField(
          focusNode: myFocusNode,
          autocorrect: false,
          enableSuggestions: false,
          toolbarOptions:
             const ToolbarOptions(copy: false, cut: false, paste: false),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
          autofocus: true,
          maxLines: null,
          controller: textEditor,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            fillColor: Colors.grey[100],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: The same issue, it's don't work. When I pressed the button nothing past.

Answer (score 1):

if  next line button show inside keyboard, so use only two line

```
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line : **textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,**
remove this line : **keyboardType: TextInputType.text,**

```
TextField(
           //keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
             textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
             maxLines: 30,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
             border: InputBorder.none,
             labelStyle: greyTextStyle400,
             hintStyle: greyTextStyle400,
             hintText: "Message...",
            ),
          ),
```